# How to display data differently for different devices in MVC 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Suprisingly after numerous searches I can't find a solution or similar question, could be a brain fart moment. I want to display data differently on different devices using media queries.

So on **large devices** I want to show in **table form**, and on **mobile devices** a custom **"listview"**.

I can achieve this by creating 2 loops through the model like so:

```
<div class="row display-large">
    <!--TABLE HERE-->
    @foreach (var emp in Model)
    <!--EACH ROW-->
</div>

<div class="row display-small">
    @foreach (var emp in Model)
    <!--EACH CUSTOM LIST ITEM-->
</div>
```

Then using media queries, I can show/hide the relevant one (display-small/large).
But I couldn't live with myself doing this,it increases page size and just very bad practice, so my question is how can I achieve this without duplicating HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the differences between the layouts will include limited functionality on mobile devices and completely different layout, So that is why i can't just play with bootstrap and "responsive" CSS features.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like this :

Create global var somewhere on server side like

```
public static class GlobalVars
{
     public static bool IsLarge {get; set;}
}
```

Add to controller something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetDisplayMode(bool isLarge)
{
    GlobalVars.IsLarge = isLarge;
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

In your view add:

```
<script>
 var data = $( window ).width() > 720)? true : false;
 $.post("@Url.Action("SetDisplayMode", "$ControllerNameHere")", { isLarge: data});     
</script>

<div class="row display-small">
    @foreach (var emp in Model)
    if(Web.GlobalVars.IsLarge) { <!--EACH ROW-->} else { <!--EACH CUSTOM LIST ITEM--> }
</div>
```

Change $ControllerNameHere to your controller name

Comment: I actually do this with other properties, "disabled" etc. , can't believe it didn't cross my mind, going to test with some state changing, re-sizing etc. and see what others say, if it remains the best solution for a couple hours, I will accept as answer thanks A LOT.

Comment: It seem to be a simplest of what you can do here but it should work

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, how can you "check for display size" from server side...You can't really...

Comment: Updated my answer. Try something like this